# Array List in dotnet highchart

Tags: c#, sql-server, dotnethighcharts

Can anyone tell me How do I bind Arraylist with dotnet highchart so that I can create the high chart with using SQL Server Data?

I have managed to copy Data from SQL Server to array list below is the code

```
using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=INBDQ2WK2LBCD2S\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MCAS;Integrated Security=SSPI"))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select top(100) * from Test4 order by Id desc", cnn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "Test4");

            List<string> xValues = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["Test4"].Rows)
            {
                xValues.Add(row["x"].ToString());
            }
            Response.Write(xValues);
```

Now I want to create highcharts. how do I bind this arraylist with highchart?

Answer (score 0):

DotNetHighCharts uses object[] when making the series for the graph.

e.g.  new Series { Data = new Data(object[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } }

Maybe make it a `List<object>` instead of a `List<string>`

```
        In code behind:

        List<object> values_List = new List<object>();
        object[] values = values_List.ToArray();

        Highcharts chart1 = new Highcharts("Chart1")
        .InitChart(new Chart { Height = 300, Width = 400, Type = ChartTypes.Column })
        .SetSeries(new Series { Data = new Data(values)});            

        ltrChart1.Text = chart1.ToHtmlString();



        In aspx:

        <asp:Literal ID="ltrChart1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```